# Telephony Manager Method to see if the phone has a network

Tags: android, telephony

Is there any method in telephony manager which can be used to see if the phone has any network?By that i mean i want to check if the phone has a telephone network, not if its has a data network. For example, if the user puts his phone on airplane mode, that means he doesn't have phone network to receive calls, send SMS etc. That's exactly the kind of thing i want to detect. Is there any method to do so?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static boolean checkMobileNetworkAvailable(Context context){
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int networkType = tm.getNetworkType();
    return (networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN);
}
```

from this [so Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435861/android-what-is-the-correct-way-of-checking-for-mobile-network-available-no-da). check if it helps you