# How to check if a cell tower connection exists?

Tags: android, cellular-network

In my android app I have to gather a lot of information regarding the cell tower
like Network name, Network code etc etc but before I start capturing all those
things I want to make sure that a cell tower connections exists
i.e. GSM or CDMA, but I want to ensure that there is a connection. Otherwise
I would just like to return.
For example, as we do it in case of Wi Fi. With the help of WifiManager's isWifiEnabled() method we ensure first hand whether we have Wifi running or not.

Similar to that, for Cell Tower.

Comment: I m putting as a comment because i do not know this is a solution or not for the thing you are looking for?
As described in this post http://www.anddev.org/poor_mans_gps_-_celltowerid_-_location_area_code_-lookup-t257.html you can register a broadcast receiver for phonestate and using that you can get the current CellId & LAC, so based on that values you can say device connected to cell network or not.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529484/how-to-check-for-phone-network-on-android-devices) post, you can find as below

```
boolean hasNetwork = android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkType() != android.telephony.TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN; 
// True if the phone is connected to some type of network i.e. has signal
```

Another way from same link, but not marked as solution, is to check for network operator field as below

```
public static Boolean isMobileAvailable(Context appcontext) {       
    TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) appcontext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);       
    return ((tel.getNetworkOperator() != null && tel.getNetworkOperator().equals("")) ? false : true);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
   Context context = getApplicationContext();
   ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   if (connectivity == null) {
      boitealerte(this.getString(R.string.alert),"getSystemService rend null");
   } else {
      NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
      if (info != null) {
         for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
            if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
               return true;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

*It will return true if the network is available.*